# Поиск организации по id в API поиска по организациям

Tags: яндекс-карты, yandex-places-api

Подскажите, пожалуйста, можно ли получить данные по организации, зная ее id? Использую API поиска по организациям от Яндекс.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В JS API Яндекс Карт такой поиск выполняет функция [findOrganization](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/findOrganization.html).

Comment: Я так понял, это чтобы найти на карте данный объект. А мне нужно сделать запрос к API поиска по организациям, чтобы по id получить данные об организации. Пример: `https://search-maps.yandex.ru/v1/?text=${id}&type=biz&lang=ru_RU&apikey=${process.env.API_KEY}`

Comment: Чтобы найти на карте, отобразить и получить доступ к её данным, тем же самым, что и в ППО. В ППО вы бесплатно тоже не имеете права без карты работать, которую ещё на публичной веб-странице разместить надо. Потому решение на JS API выглядит здесь более целостным и имеет ещё и больший суточный лимит запросов.